# Differentiability of a function series

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to show that $f_k (t)=\frac{t^k A^k}{k!}$ with $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is differentiable for all $k\in \mathbb{N}_{0}$. Now my intuition tells me: $\frac{d}{dt}f_k (t)= \frac{d}{dt} \frac{t^k A^k}{k!} = \frac{t^{(k-1)} A^k}{(k-1)!}$ but how do I prove this? Should I just start with k=1 and then go on?

Comment: What exactly is your difficulty in computing the derivative of a constant multiple of $t^k$?

Comment: Hey, I want to somehow put it into the derivative formula and use the matrix-norm. Do I need to do it? If so, I have problems with the different norms in the formula then and how to show it for all k.

Comment: This then reduces to proving that $|(t+h)^k-t^k-kt^{k-1}h|=o(h)$, as in the scalar case. The task of proving that the derivative of the exponential series or any power series is the term-wise derivative is slightly more difficult.